# How can I append a {{link-to}} helper to my template dynamically in ember.js? (Functionality similiar to $compile in angular)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember 2.0 with ember-cli. All the other answers that come close to addressing this all use deprecated methods.

Currently I have some code that looks like this inside a component called `object-form` that I use in several places:

```
saveObject(newObject) {
  newObject.save().then((object) => {
    this.$('.success-message')
      .html('Object "' + object.get('name') +
            '" successfully added.')
  }
}
```

This works fine, but now I'd have to also have something like:

```
$('.success-message').append('{{link-to object.name "object.show" object}}')
```

However, as expected, the text is added exactly as written instead of being added as an actual `{{link-to}}` helper.

In angular, which I'm more familiar with, you used something called the `$compile` service to dynamically add directives, the equivalent of ember components.

If `link-to` existed in angular, for example, the pseudocode would look like something like this:

```
var directive = $compile('<link-to ng-href="/object/{{object.id}} ng-model=object">{{object.name}}</link-to>')($scope);
$('.success-message').append(directive);
```

So is there an equivalent method of parsing the handlebars inside a string you want to append?

Comment: It might be possible, but it's definitely not advisable. If you find yourself needing to manually add things to the DOM, you're not using Ember correctly.

Comment: @GJK wow right after reading your comment I realized how to solve my problem. Thank you it was a simple comment but eye-opening.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Also, don't feel bad about not getting the hang of things right away. Ember is not an easy framework to learn, trust me. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dynamically appending the `{{link-to}}` it makes much more sense to just put it under an if statement, which behind the scenes is really doing the same thing I intended.